# Oracle SQL: Update Table with SUM OVER PARTITION

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, window-functions

I've been trying to do the following:

```
CREATE TABLE T_example
(category number(1,0),
amount number(4,0),
amount2 number(4,0))

INSERT INTO T_example VALUES (1,20,40);
INSERT INTO T_example VALUES (1,30,40);
INSERT INTO T_example VALUES (2,5,60);
INSERT INTO T_example VALUES (2,15,60);
INSERT INTO T_example VALUES (2,30,60);
```

As you can see all rows contain the same amount2 within their category. Now i want to spread amount2 within each category according to the distribution of amount with the category.

```
UPDATE T_example
SET amount2 = amount2 * amount / SUM(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY category);
```

I want to get:

```
category - amount - amount2
1 - 20 - 16
1 - 30 - 24
2 - 5 - 6
2 - 15 - 18
2 - 30 - 36
```

But the code doesn't work. It says:

> 00934.00000 -  "group function is not allowed here"

Can you tell me where I am mistaken?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think below will work for you,co-related sub-query

```
 UPDATE T_example t1
    SET t1.amount2 = (t1.amount*t1.amount2) / (

       select sum(amount) from -- from was missing
      T_example t2 where t2.category=t1.category
      group by category

            );
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e2c00fe7ad8866bb4a62f66b08133f95

```
CATEGORY    AMOUNT  AMOUNT2
1            20     16
1            30     24
2             5     6
2            15     18
2            30     36
```

Comment: That does work but it seems quite complicated since i want to do it for multiple columns in the real case. Is there no way to make SUM... OVER work in this Scenario?

Comment: @JForFun you can try by creating sub-query in that it may work